# ¿Por qué no se carga la petición?

Tags: formularios, webforms, pug

Tengo un frontend con pug, lo que hago es un modal, dentro un formulario, le pongo el médoto, y no debería de enviar nada porque no está echa la parte del frontend, pero debería de intentar recargar la página como si enviara y recibiera la petición, sin embargo no lo hace, acá mi pug:

```
#register.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel', aria-hidden='true')
        .modal-dialog(role='document')
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    h5#exampleModalLabel.modal-title.h5.text-center.mb-4 Sign up
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
                        span(aria-hidden='true') ×
                .modal-body
                    .form(method='post', action="/")
                        .md-form
                            i.fa.fa-envelope.prefix.grey-text
                            input.form-control(type='text', id='defaultForm-email')
                            label(for='defaultForm-email') Email
                        .md-form
                            i.fa.fa-lock.prefix.grey-text
                            input.form-control(type='password', id='defaultForm-email')
                            label(for='defaultForm-email') Password
                        .md-form
                            i.fa.fa-lock.prefix.grey-text
                            input.form-control(type='password', id='defaultForm-email')
                            label(for='defaultForm-email') Repeat Password
                        .text-center
                            button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Register
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona?

Comment: Donde pones `.form` debería ser `form` sin el punto para que cree una etiqueta `<form>` y no un `<div class="form">`

Comment: Ya me di cuenta, gracias.